# Cannot find module '@angular/forms'

Tags: forms, validation, angular, ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic 2/Angular app and I'm trying to use form validation following this tutorial:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

But the compiler says:

> Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.

Why is this modules not available? Is it deprecated?

Comment: Does `systemjs.config.js` contain `@angular/forms` reference? I mean, do you load it through `systemjs` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. It doesn't contains a systemjs.config.js and it is not even available at node_modules/@angular. Does I need to install it from npm? It's an Ionic 2  templated installed via 'ionic start' command ans uses gulp.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an ionic guy. Better to wait for others to reply.

Comment: Although it's an Ionic 2 project I think the Angular thing must be similar. Inside the node_modules/@angular folder should not be a forms folder? – Natanael 16 secs ago    edit

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: According to my package.json it seem to be 2.0.0-rc.3.

Answer (score 12):

Try `npm install @angular/forms --save`

It will warn you that you should be using 2.0.0-rc.4 though.  This may come with it's own set of upgrade challenges...

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem, my solution was:

1) add forms to the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@angular/forms":   "0.2.0",
...
}
```

2) install using npm in the console, type within the app folder

```
npm install
```

3) run app again

```
npm start
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Vielen Dank Mein Freund :) !

Answer (score 3):

Run this command `npm install @angular/forms --save`

Go to package.json and double check to make sure this dependency is present `@angular/forms: "{your version}",` and save the changes.

Close and reopen your IDE and go back to app.module.ts. Remove the import statement and retype it again, then it should work.

Thank You

Comment: I would just like to say that I found this post as I was running into this issue in a recent project.  Your comment about go back and retyping worked for me.  I would cut and past the line with the issue. Save and then paste the line back in. Fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This worked for me also. I did not need to close my IDE or save (--save does that). After running the install command and retyping the last part of the import statement it worked for me. Made a suggested edit to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when updating versions I see messages like this:

```
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'R:\TFS\RRCRM\RRCRM\node_modules\@angular\forms' -> 'R:\TFS\RRCRM\RRCRM\node_modules\@angular\.forms.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'R:\TFS\RRCRM\RRCRM\node_modules\@angular\forms' -> 'R:\TFS\RRCRM\RRCRM\node_modules\@angular\.forms.DELETE']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'R:\\TFS\\RRCRM\\RRCRM\\node_modules\\@angular\\forms',
npm ERR!   dest: 'R:\\TFS\\RRCRM\\RRCRM\\node_modules\\@angular\\.forms.DELETE',
npm ERR!   parent: 'rrcrm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     R:\TFS\RRCRM\RRCRM\npm-debug.log
```

I belive it can be due to file in use errors sometimes (I'm running Visual Studio on Windows as administrator).

Make sure nothing is running that might have a file lock on any packages - such as angular CLI. So close any windows or processes and run something like `npm install` again.

Answer (score -1):

I had a weird situation where I can not do npm install, and had to copy the libs from shared path. Copy the "forms" folder under node_modules/@angaular solved the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Is **import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';** is injected in app.module.ts and added FormsModule array in the imports as below

```
    app.module.ts
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule
    ]
```